# Finding and updating duplicate values in database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How to accomplish the following scenario on a MySQL database.

1. Find duplicate records matching EMAIL id.
2. Then from records from 1st step, find duplicate matching multiple column.(b,c,d)
3. Then from records from 2nd step, update a column(isParent) whose created date(a column) is highest.

For example -

1. Database records

```
Email   Firstname   Lastname    Address created_date    is_Parent
abc@123.com John    Abraham India   12/12/22    
abc@123.com John    Abraham India   12/12/21    
abc@123.com John    Abraham Bangladesh  11/12/22    
abc@123.com John    Abraham Srilanka    10/01/21    
abc@123.com Shahrukh    Khan    India   01/02/12    
abc@123.com Shahrukh    Khan    India   01/03/12    
xyz@123.com Shahrukh    Khan    Bangladesh  10/12/13    
xyz@123.com Shahrukh    Khan    Pakistan    01/02/21    
xyz@123.com Shahrukh    Khan    Pakistan    11/02/21    
xyz@123.com Salman  Khan    Uganda  11/12/22    
xyz@123.com Salman  Khan    Uganda  11/11/22    
xyz@123.com Salman  Khan    Sudan   02/03/21    
xyz@123.com Salman  Khan    Sudan   04/03/21    
xyz@123.com Salman  Khan    Sudan   01/02/21    
unique@cute.com Kamal   R.Khan  China   01/02/21
```

2. From step 1st I should get all the record with Email id abc@123.com and xyz@123.com not unique@cute.com
3. from 2nd step I should get record no# 2,3,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
4. It should update the "isParent" column with value 1 for record no.# 2,7,10,11,14

I am using

```
SELECT `FirstName`,`LastName`,`Address` SF_dup_leads.Email,
FROM SF_dup_leads 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Email FROM SF_dup_leads GROUP BY `FirstName`,`LastName`,`Address` HAVING COUNT(Email) > 1) dup ON SF_dup_leads.Email = dup.Email
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Where are the columns b, c, and d where the email would be? They are not in your example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use *SQL windows functions* to solve this problem.

For example, you can use `DENSE_RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` functions in this case:

*Example (please, review the query before running):*

```
   SELECT Email,FirstName,LastName,Address,Created_Date,
          CASE WHEN Rank = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Is_Parent
     FROM (SELECT Email,FirstName,LastName,Address,Created_Date,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Created_Date ASC) AS Rank
             FROM <your_table>)
```

Comment: Above query is giving out following error
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Created_Date ASC) AS Rank`
             FROM SF_dup' at line 4

Comment: Zuhaib,  maybe we need do add an space after the OVER clausule.  Please, modify to ".. ROW_NUMBER()   OVER   (PARTITION BY ...."    You can review de ROW_NUMBER syntax in this link: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/   . Regards!